# Configure nginx vhosts by path

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I want to serve my projects by first item in the path, for example http://example.com/projectname should serve a project in /usr/share/nginx/html/projectname.

This is what my configurations look like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/ssl/XX.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/ssl/XX.key";
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    server_name  example.com/$1 www.example.com/$1;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

    location /projectname {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/projectname ;
        index  index.html;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
    }
}
```

Observation:
When i visit the configured domain it routes to nginx defualt page instead of displaying the expected project.

Comment: That's probably because of `/$1` in server names.

Comment: @anemyte it still not working wth /$1 removed

Comment: Check whether the config in question is really imported into `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and see what other config files are imported. Look for `include` statements in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, one of them should match the config file in question by glob or directly, e.g. `include conf.d/*.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

3 Changes:

1. Instead of rewrite, do return 301
2. In second server block, don't have `/$1` at the end of server_names
3. remove `index index.html` from `location /projectname` block

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com/$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/ssl/XX.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/ssl/XX.key";
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

    location /projectname {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/projectname ;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
    }
}
```

Try this and it should work.

Comment: I have made the changes  which seem to work but now the react project can't load in browser. Am getting <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>   but i can see the project files logged in the sources tab. Do you have any information on this!

Comment: Sorry but I don't know about that... If this answer has helped with NGINX part of the answer, don't forget to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**1:** Open sudo vi /etc/hosts file in you Linux machine

**2:** `127.0.0.1 example.com www.example.com`

**3:** Save and exit.

Comment: I am still seeing the same behaviour

Comment: Did you try `^(.*)` in your rewrite-regex stmt. `rewrite ^(.*) https://example.com/$1`

Comment: did you reload also ?

Comment: I did a restart of nginx service